# Firefox 35.0a2 displays nothing when working with polymer 0.4.2

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, polymer

Firefox goes as far as the         then it keeps "loading" but does not load any component or anything at all.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title class="titulo"></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/platform/platform.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html"> 
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-icon-button/core-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-icons/core-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-icon/core-icon.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-drawer-panel/core-drawer-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html"> 
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-viva/core-viva-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-viva/core-viva-submenu.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-menu/core-submenu.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-shadow/paper-shadow.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-fab/paper-fab.html">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="pagina.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="pagina.css">
</head>
<body fullbleed>
<core-ajax url="" handleAs="json"></core-ajax>
<core-drawer-panel drawerWidth="320px" >
  <core-header-panel drawer mode="standard" >
    <paper-shadow z="2">
      <core-toolbar id="topo-do-menu-lateral" class="medium-tall" >
        <div id="toolbar-content"></div>
      </core-toolbar>
      <core-menu class="menulateral" id="menulateral" z="1" selected="0"></core-menu>
    </paper-shadow>
  </core-header-panel>
  <core-header-panel id="main-content-header-panel" mode="waterfall" class="" main>
   <!-- topo com título -->
    <core-toolbar id="topo-do-titulo" class="medium-tall middleJustify">

      <paper-icon-button id="navicon" icon="menu" class="middle"></paper-icon-button>

      <div id="titulo" class="indent middle" flex></div>


        <a href="http://localhost/vivadev/pagina/" id="button_close"><paper-fab id="viva-close-button" icon="close" class="middle"></paper-fab></a>


      <paper-shadow z="1"></paper-shadow>
    </core-toolbar>
    <div id="conteudo" class="indent" flex vertical layout center>
      <responsive-embed id="responsiveEmbedContent">
      </responsive-embed>
    </div>
  </core-header-panel>
</core-drawer-panel>
</body>
</html>
```

Its all i have besides the style.css (which i can attach if you think it might help, i even copied all imports to the index.html because FF was blabing about it.
Hope someone can help me.

Comment: So, I've turned your example into a code snippet, and it works the same for me in both FF and Chrome. Your core-viva code isn't present of course, perhaps the problem is somewhere in there?

Comment: thank you for pointing it out, i'll check it out later today. btw: did you use json to  populate the view?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has something to do with Firefox same-origin policy for Ajax calls.

Have you tried setting up a web server on your localhost to serve index.html?

Comment: I am, and the json is local too. FF still gives me a "no can do" but i'll try looking into core-ajax and see if i can figure something up. yet i see no problem on chrome. same settings.

Comment: Then maybe one of the files that your components depend on is missing (or inaccessible)? I've noticed that in such cases Chrome ignores the file, but Firefox waits forever...

Comment: That is exactly my case i guess. It keeps on loading forever. i'll look into it, hopefully post an answer later today. thank you.

Comment: TypeError: t is undefined on line 13 of platform.js besides that, my content shows on firefug but as if polymer never existed fullbleed turns into fullbleed="" and such.

Comment: updated all components, and well.... no error. but wait theres more: Nothing shows up on page.

Comment: I am calling the ajax after the polymer-ready event, think it might have something to do with that? ps.: the json populates the elements with content and attrbs